# Best way to pass large number of values in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rest

I am making an iOS application that utilizes a swiping/matching feature similar to tinder. I have a MySQL database that is used to match users with people that meet the user's search criteria.
[image: Swiping feature]

The swiping feature.
 ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
 ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
[image: My users' search criteria]
My user's search criteria.
[image: What my table base of users looks like]
What my table base of users would look like.

I've created an API endpoint using php and SQL to update each user's info whenever changes are made and to get all of the nearby users that meet the user's search criteria.

Here's what the php looks like for getting nearby users.

```
$uid        = strval($_GET['uid']);
$lat        = floatval($_GET['lat']);
$lng        = floatval($_GET['lng']);
$minAge     = intval($_GET['minAge']);
$maxAge     = intval($_GET['maxAge']);
$gender     = intval($_GET['gender']);
$radius     = intval($_GET['radius']);
$type       = intval($_GET['type']);

// This SQL statement selects users from the table 'users' so long as 
//they are within x miles of the user's location and within the age 
//range and gender requirements

$sql = "SELECT *,
    (((acos(sin((?*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos((?*pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((?- `lng`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515)
    AS distance
    from users having distance<? AND gender=? AND age<? AND age>? AND type=? AND uid<>?"; 

//Bind parameters to the placeholders
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "dddiiiiis", $lat, $lat, $lng, $radius, $gender, $maxAge, $minAge, $type, $uid);

//Run parameters inside database
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

And the URL to make this request might look something like this:

```
https://mywebsitename.com/getNearbyUsers.php?uid=4pW2I1gpq5VHCHEdm0aEfTRgJO92&lat=38.461822509765625&lng=-90.32567239374883&minAge=18&maxAge=100&gender=2&radius=50&type=3
```

**My Issue:**

Now, whenever a user (user1) swipes right or left on another user (user2), I want to track that this user2 has already been presented to user1 so that they aren't presented in the future.

**What I initially planned to do:**

My first thought to solve this was to make another column in my SQL database that would essentially be an array of uids that communicate which users have already been shown to the current user. Whenever a user on the front-end (user1) swipes right or left another user's profile (user2) user2's uid could be added to the array of users that user1 has already swiped on. I could then, in the SQL statement, say to only return users that aren't in the current user's "alreadyPresentedWith" column of uids.

**The problem:**
I've researched into referencing large sets of values in SQL and found that you shouldn't have more than one value per column in a relational database. However, with my given skillset and experience, this is the only way I can imagine going about this task.

I'd just love feedback from more seasoned php/SQL developers as to which direction is best for me to go to tackle this sort of issue.

Comment: What if instead of "another column in my SQL database" you'd add another _table_? Two columns, "user A" and "user B", a line exists for every "user A" that swiped "user B". Then you'd filter out using a subquery.

Comment: the swipes on the Phone seams to be in order?  simply use the local storage in the Phone to safe the swipes id's and use a filter based (greater then MAX(swipe_id)) on that when you fetch the next set of possible swipes..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I considered doing something like this, but depending on the search criteria the user is passing in their search, the order that is returned could be altered. I feel its better to address everything on the back-end in this case.

Comment: *"I considered doing something like this, but depending on the search criteria the user is passing in their search, the order that is returned could be altered."* As i just noticed.. The return order is already non-deterministic (random) as you didn't include a deterministic `ORDER BY` with alteast one columns with a primary or unique key..  As `ORDER BY` on non unique values will give non-deterministic (random) results on tied values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a table, say `swipes`, with one row per actions.  Say:

```
create table swipes (
    swipes_id int auto_increment primary key,
    swiper_uid binary(16),
    swipee_uid binary(16),
    action varchar(5),  -- 'left', 'right', 'none'
    created_at datetime default now(),
    foreign key (swiper_uid) references persons(uid),
    foreign key (swipee_uid) references persons(uid)
);
```

**Edit from OP**
So, the solution was simple. I made the swipes table as suggested, created an API endpoint that inserts a "swipe" into the table every time a swipe occurs (in my case, we don't need to store whether the user swiped left or right) and then updated the SQL statement in my endpoint that gets nearby users.

[image: My 'swipes' table]

In the SQL statement, I added a `NOT EXISTS` check to reference the swipe table and check if an entry has the current user as the "swiper" and the user returned by the query as the "swipee." This is what the prepared statement in the php file that gets nearby users now looks like.

```
$sql = "SELECT *,
(((acos(sin((?*pi()/180)) * sin((`lat`*pi()/180))+cos((?*pi()/180)) * cos((`lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((?- `lng`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515)
AS distance
from users having distance<? AND gender=? AND age<? AND age>? AND type=? AND uid<>? AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM swipes s
               WHERE s.swiperUid=? AND u.uid=s.swipeeUid)"; 

//Bind parameters to the placeholders
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "dddiiiiiss", $lat, $lat, $lng, $radius, $gender, $maxAge, $minAge, $type, $uid, $uid);
```

Comment: That seemed to be the consensus for dealing with large sets of data (in this case uids). Its unreasonable to pass each person the user has swiped on as a parameter in a URL request, so instead we just create another table and cross reference the two. I suppose this is where SQL's 'JOIN' syntax comes in handy?

Comment: Unreasonable and practically impossible. There's a size limit imposed by browsers on URL length and by RDBMSs for SQL query length.

Comment: @DavidChopin . . . Not only `JOIN` syntax but the underlying mechanisms of relational databases that optimize queries.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, great. I appreciate the feedback. I am a front-end dev first and only dabble in this back-end stuff. I'll look into the suggestions you made and get back if I find any success.

Comment: Whats the `uuid` datatype in this MySQL code? Seams you are mixing MySQL a bit with PostgreSQL datatypes here now? Or is the SQL meant to be pseudo code?